# How to load an image from documents directory on macOS Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, image, swiftui

I am struggling with loading an image to Image. I am making an MacOS app which is slightly different than for iOS.

I searched Internet however I found only several responses how to make it in iOS.

Please check the code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    let myUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/codegrinder/Documents/turtlerock.jpg")
    init() {
        //TODO Do something with the myUrl which is valid (not nil)
    }
    var body: some View {
        Image("turtlerock")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment:.center)
       //I need to put the param to Image what I want to load an image from myUrl

    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First click on your app target > signing & capabilities and remove the App Sandbox as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Now you can access files that are not located inside your app bundle.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let image = NSImage(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/codegrinder/Documents/turtlerock.jpg"))!
    var body: some View {
        Image(nsImage: image)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment:.center)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I was trying NSImage but I didn't remove "App Sandbox". Thank you.